# How to split a PDF with PyMuPDF (with a loop)?

Tags: python, pymupdf

I'd like to use PyMuPDF : I'd like to split a pdf, with for each splitted file, a file named with the name of the bookmark, with only page

I've succefully my files, for exemple 4 PDF files for a 4 pages PDF source.... but in the several pdf, I don't have one page but with a random number of page ?

```
import sys, fitz

file = '/home/ilyes/Bulletins_Originaux.pdf'
bookmark = ''
try:
    doc = fitz.open(file) 
    toc = doc.getToC(simple = True)
    
except Exception as e:
    print(e)


for i in range(len(toc)):
    
    documentPdfCible=toc[i][1]
    documentPdfCibleSansSlash=documentPdfCible.replace("/","-")
    
    numeroPage=toc[i][2]
    
    
    pagedebut=numeroPage
    pagefin=numeroPage + 1
    
    print (pagedebut)
    print (pagefin)
     
    doc2 = fitz.open(file)
    
    doc2.insertPDF(doc, from_page = pagedebut, to_page = pagefin, start_at = 0)
    
    doc2.save('/home/ilyes/' + documentPdfCibleSansSlash + ".pdf")
    doc2.close
```

Could you tell me what's wrong ?
Maybee because I use always "doc2" in the loop ?

Thanks you,

Abou Ilyès

Comment: Can you provide a sample PDF file so it is easier for me to debug?

Comment: You want to insert pages before the original file?
Also, what is pagefin for?

Answer (score 4):

Seems weird, that you open the same document twice.

You open your pdf **file** at `doc = fitz.open(file)` and again at `doc2 = fitz.open(file)`.

Then you insert pages into the same file by `doc2.insertPDF(doc, from_page = pagedebut, to_page = pagefin, start_at = 0)`.

Of course the doc files toc will get messed up completely by "randomly" inserting pages.

I recommend to replace `doc2 = fitz.open(file)` with `doc2 = fitz.open()`

This will create an empty "in memory" pdf ([see the documentation](https://pymupdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/document.html#Document)), in which you can then insert the pages you need from doc. Then save this as a new pdf by its bookmark title by running

`doc2.save('/home/ilyes/' + documentPdfCibleSansSlash + ".pdf")`